How can I stop KDE widgets from moving when I return from a different activity with different screen resolution?
I recently bought a new laptop (ASUS ROG Strix SCAR ).  It has a 2560x1440 pixel screen, which is great for my imaging work, but makes text hard for me to read.  So, I set up three activities, one with 2560x1440, one 1689x1050, and one 1280x720.  I use the higher resolution for my imaging and graphics, and then the lower resolution ones for reading blogs, emails, and writing documents.  I change resolutions on entering the activity by means of an xrandr script that runs on activation, e.g. xrandr --output eDP --mode 1680x1050
The problem I have is that I have different widgets in each activity.  Fig 1 is a screenshot of my high resolution screen (which I call "4k").  Fig 2 is a screenshot of my lower resolution screen (which I call "2K").   When I switch from the 2K screen back to the 4K screen, the widgets rearrange as shown in Fig 3.
Fig1:

Fig2:

Fig3 (upon return):

My workaround is to create a second 4K activity that has no widgets (which I call activity "4K play").  When I want to switch back from 2K to 4K, if I quickly go 2K -> 4K play -> 4K.  Then widget positions are preserved.
What I believe is happening is that when I go directly from 2K to 4K, the widgets are rearranged as if it were a 2K screen before the xrandr script is run changing it to 4K.  But I don't know.
Is there a better way to preserve widget positions when changing screen resolution between activities?
